# Is there a way to replicate the information return in the Sharing Hierarchy view using Apex?

Tags: apex, sharing, sharing-rule

I'm wondering if there is a reasonably simple way to using Apex to return the data shown *for one particular user* in the "Sharing Hierarchy" view?

Looking at individual users in the Sharing Hierarchy for a record, the reasons why a user can have access can amount to exactly matching information returned by SObject "Share" records:

- Owner
- There is a rule that shares it with a user, group, or role.

But, where it gets tricky is to determine whether a user might have access due to being above the owner, user, or group member in the role hierarchy (plus, potentially, their subordinates).

Looping through each sharing rule, determining the users that have direct access, and then looping through the role hierarchy for each case determining who else has access seems difficult, and computationally expensive, especially in an org with a lot of sharing rules.

Yet Salesforce returns the entire list of users with access immediately. Probably this is all cleverly computed beforehand behind the scenes.

But, I wonder if anyone knows of any ways to programmatically list the reasons why one user has access to a particular record?

Thanks

Comment: If you haven't already, I would recommend reading through the [Record-Level Access: Under the Hood](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood.meta/salesforce_record_access_under_the_hood/uth_preface.htm) resource. This has a lot of information on how Salesforce manages sharing in the background. Essentially, 2 'Sharing' tables are maintained, one being the Object Sharing (Share records) and one the Group Maintenance Tables. These are pre-calculated when configuration changes, not in real-time which is why we have access so quickly.